# Regular Expression: Match only last square brackets

Tags: regex

I am filtering some messages in **JavaScript** and I need to select the last square bracket value (including square brackets `[` and `]`) and replace it with `:`.

As an example:
`[World] [anything] [any] steamName`**[characterName]:**`message`
Wanna change to:
`[World] [anything] [any] steamName: message`

This `[characterName]:` is what I want to be reclaced by a `:`

**I've tried the following regular expressions:**
This one doesn't work with an space in the middle of the name.
**[`\[(\S*?)\]:`](http://regexr.com/3f11i)** 
(link to regexr.com)

This one only works if there is only one [squareBracket] with an space before it as you can see in the link.
**[`\[(.*?)\]:`](http://regexr.com/3f11l)**
(link to regexr.com)

I need like a mix between the two that works in every case.
I'd like you to provide me the regexp I am looking for with the link to regexr.com **with the following cases (matching strong words)** to prove that it works:

`Hi!I'm a Player!1`**[Hi!I'm a Player!1]:**`message`
`[VIP] [Admin] Hi!I'm admin`**[Hi!I'm admin]:**`message`
`[VIP] Player`**[Player]:**`message`
`[VIP] [any] Player`**[(#@#Player !123)]:**`some message`
`[VIP] [any] 3number2`**[121223]:**`message`
`[Area] [bla] [bla] anyth1ng`**[[[[[[((something#]]]:**`message message message`

I think it's important to add that there will be always a square bracket before the colon: `[this]:`, which is what I want it to match for replace.

I hope I've been clear enough. Feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: Your last case: will the opening/closing brackets always be coupled together or can they be wildly mixed. If the latter, how to determine, what exactly belongs inside and whats from the outside?

Comment: Is the last `[]` always followed by `:`? (If so see @Maslo's answer)

Comment: Why negative? I guess I wasn't clear in my question? Hope should I improve it?

Comment: @BrunoLM @Maslo's answer should be good for PHP and Python but unfortunately It won't work for JavaScript, not sure why. Yes, the last `[]` if followed by `:` always.

Comment: @SebastianProske the content of the `[]` will be determined by the user's nickname, they may be using weird symbols in their name, including square brackets `[` or `]` or chinese characters. So it could be just anything there. I just need to match the last square brackets followed by a colon `:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var msg = `Hi!I'm a Player!1[Hi!I'm a Player!1]:message
[VIP] [Admin] Hi!I'm admin[Hi!I'm admin]:message
[VIP] Player[Player]:message
[VIP] [any] Player[(#@#Player !123)]:some message
[VIP] [any] 3number2[121223]:message
[Area] [bla] [bla] anyth1ng[[[[[[((something#]]]:message message message`;

var newMsg = msg.replace(/\[[^\]]*\]+:/g, ': ');

console.log(newMsg);
```

Regex [explanation from Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/f0GHkK/3)

`/\[[^\]]*\]+:/g`

- `\[` matches the character `[` literally (case sensitive)
- Match a single character not present in the list below `[^\]]*`

  - `*` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
  - `\]` matches the character `]` literally (case sensitive)
  - `\]+` matches the character `]` literally (case sensitive)
  - `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- `:` matches the character `:` literally (case sensitive)
- Global pattern flags

  - `g` modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. @Maslo's answer it's still good for other languages though.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
\[[^]]*\]+:
```

https://regex101.com/r/f0GHkK/1

Comment: @JoseSerodio Try `\[[^\]]*\]+:`, he just forgot to escape `]` (`\]`)

Answer (score 1):

Use a negative look ahead for another square braket:

```
\[[^\]]*\](?!.*])
```

The whole match is your target, soyiur repkamwnt string is jusr `":"` (no need for groups).

Comment: Almost, but it doesn't work for the last case. It seems that if you place another `]` inside the brackets won't match: `[something]]`

Comment: You need a parser. Regex can't handle arbitrary nesting. You've changed the question. I'm out.